# Access original data in request POST

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Using Django 1.7. 
In a Function Based View, I'm trying to get the data of the *current* (i.e. not yet updated) instance to do a comparison which action I need to take.

When I try to get the data using `smt.field1`, I'd expect to get what I have in the database for this instance, but instead I get the new, unsaved data that is in the form.

```
def edit_something(request, pk):

    smt = get_object_or_404(Something, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = MyForm(instance=smt, data=request.POST)
        context_dict['form'] = form
        if form.is_valid():

            if smt.field1 != form.cleaned_data.get('field1'):
                print "field1 has changed, so I need to do Action1"
            else:
                print "field1 has not changed, so I need to do Action2"

            form.instance.modified_by = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('smt_detail', args=(smt.id,)))
    else:
       ...
```

In other words, the `smt.field1 == form.cleaned_data.get('field1')` will always yield `True` and Action1 will always be taken. I don't want this.

Any idea how to elegantly solve this?

Comment: Don't you mean `if smt.field1 != form.cleaned_data.get('field1)` ?

Comment: @Brandon: yes indeed, that was a typo. Changed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use form.changed_data to get at which fields have been updated.

Comment: Thanks, that's more elegant than the solution I found (below). I ended up with `if 'field1' in form.changed_data:`

Answer (score 0):

The instance of `smt` gets changed when `if form.is_valid():` is called.

One solution is to get the smt.field1 variable *before* calling form.is_valid(), e.g.

```
...
    form = MyForm(instance=smt, data=request.POST)
    context_dict['form'] = form
    orig_field1 = smt.field1
    if form.is_valid():

        if orig_field1 != form.cleaned_data.get('field1'):
            print "field1 has changed, so I need to do Action1"
        else:
            print "field1 has not changed, so I need to do Action2"
...
```